# Como criar a condição booleana AND em um código .bat?

Tags: bat

Tenho um programa simples que deleta certos arquivos caso existam, mas gostaria de aperfeiçoá-lo utilizando uma condição booleana para caso os dois arquivos não existam. É possível de forma simples? Achei respostas em inglês mas todas são muito antigas (2010 ou mais antigas) e involve comandos que desconheço e são confusos, criar variáveis, etc.

Parte do código que uso no momento, funciona perfeitamente:

```
echo. & echo "Deletar WoWCombatLog.txt" & echo.
    
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs\WoWCombatLog.txt" (
        echo "CombatLog não encontrado"
    )
```

Como eu gostaria que funcionasse (não há motivos para postar todo o código):

```
echo. & echo "Deletar WoWCombatLog.txt" & echo.
        
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs\WoWCombatLog.txt" AND NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs\WoWCombatLog-split*.txt"  (
            echo "CombatLog não encontrado"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se as duas condições têm que ser verdadeiras, coloque uma aninhada na outra.

```
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs\WoWCombatLog.txt" (
    IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs\WoWCombatLog-split*.txt" (
        echo "CombatLog não encontrado"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `dir` com múltiplos arquivos e use o `errorlevel`

```batch-file
set "_wow_path=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs"

2>nul >nul dir /b "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog.txt" "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog-split*.txt"
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo\Arquivo(s) encontrado(s)!
```

- Ou em bloco com uso de operadores `(dir arq1.txt arq*.txt) &&`  listou 1 (ou 2) `||` não listou nada:

```batch-file
set "_wow_path=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs"

( dir /b "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog.txt" "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog-split*.txt"
) 2>nul >nul && echo\Arquivo(s) encontrado(s)! || echo\Arquivos nao encontrados!!
```

---

**1.** Define o path para a pasta dos arquivos que desejas verificar:

```batch-file
set "_wow_path=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs"
```

**2.** Execute um comando para listar, como o **`dir arquivo1 arquivo2`**

```batch-file
 dir /b "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLogX.txt" "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog-split*X.txt"
```

**3.** Limite a execução acima num bloco **`(dir arquivo1 arquivo2) 2>nul >nul`** e suprimir qualquer erro(s) de *`arquivo não encontrado`*:

```batch-file
( dir /b "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog.txt" "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog-split*.txt"
) 2>nul >nul && Arquivo(s) sim encontrado(s)! || echo\Arquivos nao encontrados!!
```

- **Obs.: 1** Ou use uma só linha no bloco:

```batch-file
( dir /b "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog.txt" "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog-split*.txt" ) 2>nul >nul && echo\Arquivo(s) encontrado(s) || echo\Arquivos nao encontrados!!
```

- **Obs.: 2** você pode passar por parâmetro mais de um arquivo para o comando **`dir`**
  ***`dir /b arq1.log arq2.txt arq3.dat...`**, se um apenas um arquivo for listado, dir retorna **`return 0`** e se nenhum for listado, **`return non 0`**.

---

**4** Utilize o operador **`&&`** para tratar **`return 0`** e o operador **`||`** para tratar **`return non 0`**:

---

```batch-file
rem :: lógica aplicada na listagem de 2(+) arquivo(s) ⁄⁄ mensagens ::

rem :: Não listou os 2 arquivos  ==  ||  Arquivos nao encontrados
rem :: Sim listou os 2 arquivos  ==  &&  Arquivo(s) encontrado(s)!   
rem :: Não listou 1 dos arquivos ==  &&  Arquivo(s) encontrado(s)! 

rem :: Output/saídas nas listagem de 2(+) arquivo(s) ⁄⁄ mensagens ::
rem :: Arquivo(s) nao encontrado(s) (dir) || mensagem 
rem :: Nao exist True  ==  WoWCombatLog-split 
rem :: Nao exist True  ==  WoWCombatLog-split*.txt
rem ::    Return "1"   ==  Arquivos nao encontrados

rem :: Um Arquivo encontrado (dir) && mensagem 
rem :: Nao exist False  ==  WoWCombatLog-split 
rem :: Nao exist False  ==  WoWCombatLog-split*.txt
rem ::     Return "0"   ==  Arquivo(s) encontrado(s)

rem :: Um ou (*) Arquivos encontrados (dir) && mensagem 
rem :: Nao exist True   ==  WoWCombatLog-split 
rem :: Nao exist False  ==  WoWCombatLog-split*.txt
rem ::     Return "1"   ==  Arquivo(s) encontrado(s)

rem :: Um ou (*) Arquivos encontrados (dir) && mensagem 
rem :: Nao exist False  ==  WoWCombatLog-split 
rem :: Nao exist True   ==  WoWCombatLog-split*.txt
rem ::     Return "1"   ==  Arquivo(s) encontrado(s)
```

---

```batch-file
rem :: para apagar os dois arquivos somente se existirem: 

set "_wow_path_files=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs"

2>nul >nul dir /b "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog.txt" "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog-split*.txt"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 del /q /f "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog.txt" "%_wow_path%\WoWCombatLog-split*.txt"
```

---

## Resumindo:

- Somente se **não** existirem **os dois** (ou mais: `...split*.txt`)

```batch-file
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs"
2>nul >nul dir WoWCombatLog-split*.txt WoWCombatLog.txt || echo\Arquivos Nao Encontrados
```

- Resulta:

```batch-file
Arquivos Nao Encontrados
```

- Somente se **existe(m) 1 ou mais** // `...split*.txt`

```batch-file
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs"
2>nul >nul dir WoWCombatLog-split*.txt WoWCombatLog.txt && echo\Arquivo(s) Encontrado(s)
```

- Resulta:

```batch-file
Arquivo(s) Encontrado(s)
```

- As duas opções acima em um bat:

```batch-file
@echo off 

cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs"
>nul 2>&1 dir WoWCombatLog-split*.txt WoWCombatLogx.txt && <nul ^
echo\Arquivo(s) Encontrado(s) || echo\Arquivos nao Encontrados
```

- Apagando esses arquivos caso **dois** ou **mais existirem**:

```batch-file
@echo off 

cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\_retail_\Logs"
>nul 2>&1 dir/b WoWCombatLog-split*.txt WoWCombatLog.txt && <nul ^
    del /q /f WoWCombatLog-split*.txt WoWCombatLog.txt >nul 2>&1 ^
        || echo\Arquivos nao Encontrados
```

---